# MaxReceivedMessageSize: why both in client and server in a one-way call?

Tags: wcf

Hi everybody I'm trying to fully understand WCF configuration options. There is a thing that I fully don't understand. Why should I say to the client and to the server that the MaxReceivedMessageSize is x KB?
I mean I have a service that exposes a set of fire-and-forget calls (no callback). Why should the client know how much is the MaxReceivedMessageSize? What happens if I don't tell anything to the client? Will it use the default size so if the message is bigger than that it exceeds?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The client configuration is used only when client receives messages (responses) so in your case you don't have to setup MaxReceivedMessageSize on the client at all - it will never be used.

Answer (score 0):

While developing my own services, I have seen a lot of references on the net saying to specify it on both ends...But as @Ladislav mentioned, I found this not necessarily a requirement. When a client sends a big message a service certainly needs this setting, ***but*** if the service "reply" (or lack of it in case of IsOneWay) is not big, then client does not need this setting...At least this has been my experience.